# jordan canonical form and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a Jordan canonical form for $A$ from the given data:

$A$ is $8\times8$

$(A+iI)$ has rank $4$

$(A+iI)^2$ has rank $2$

$(A+iI)^{3}$ has rank $1$

$(A+iI)^{k}=0$ for $k\geq4$

Comment: Edit your question: it is almost impossibe to understand as it is now. Also, add any work you've done so far in it.

Comment: ok thanks .i edited it

Comment: If you try to write plain text enclosed in two dollar signs it is going to get ugly...Do you have an $\;8\times 8\;$ matrix, s.t $\;A+I\;$ has rank 4 and etc. ,right?

Comment: Wow. Even plain text was written in Latex.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$: $\operatorname{rk}(A - \lambda I)^{n-1} - \operatorname{rk}(A - \lambda I)^n$ is the number of Jordan blocks associated with $\lambda$ that have size at least $n$.

In particular, we can gather that the Jordan form in question has (associated with the eigenvalue $i$)

- $4$ blocks in total
- $2$ of size at least $2$
- $1$ of size at least $3$
- $1$ of size at least $4$
- no blocks of size greater than $4$